# Adding pattern or hatch to bar graph using R plotly

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-plotly

I'm creating bar graphs in R, and want to add a specific pattern or hatch depending on the value of a specific (binary) feature. Does anyone know of a way to do this in plotly? I've seen it done in ggplot and in python, but not in this case.

Edit: Say the data is plot_data

```
x_var y_var color_var pattern_var
1     4     name_1    1
2     3     name_2    0
3     6     name_1    0
4     3     name_1    1
5     7     name_2    1
```

Right now my code for making the plot is:

```
plot_ly(data = plot_data) %>%
    add_bars(
        x = ~x_var,
        y = ~y_var,
        color = ~color_var,
    )
```

so that there are 5 bars of different heights that have two different colors depending on whether they are name_1 or name_2. I want to also have them have a pattern depending on whether pattern_var is 1 or 0, so that if pattern_var is 0, the bar is filled in completely by the color, and if pattern_var is 1, it has stripes or some other pattern.

Comment: Hi @cyeager, do you have any data we can reproduci? If so the best way to share your data is using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if I knew exactly what you wanted, but this works to show you how patterns are documented in the function call.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = LETTERS[1:3],
        y = 6:4,
        color = letters[8:10],
        marker = list(pattern = list(shape = "x")),
        type = "bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have this but have the pattern differ depending on a variable in the data?

Comment: I'm sure there's a simpler way, but I am only aware of how to change it after creating the plotly object. If the plot above was saved to the object `plt`. Using 1, 2, or 3 in place of "?" representing the columns in the order shown: first `plt <- plotly_build(plt)` to see the traces, then `plt$x$data[[`?`]]$marker$pattern$shape <- "."` if you wanted dots in the ? column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that matches `pattern_var`to the pattern "/":

```
library(plotly)
plot_data <- data.frame(
  x_var = 1:5,
  y_var = c(4, 3, 6, 3, 7),
  color_var = c("name_1", "name_2", "name_1", "name_1", "name_2"),
  pattern_var = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)


plot_ly(data = plot_data) |> 
  add_bars(
    x = ~x_var,
    y = ~y_var,
    color = ~color_var,
    marker = list(
      pattern = list(
        shape = ~ifelse(pattern_var == 1, "/", "")
      )
    )
  )
```

[image: plotly with stripped pattern]

You can also modify the plot_data data.frame to define exactly the pattern needed in pattern_var column ("+", ".", "/", "-", etc...)

https://plotly.com/r/reference/bar/#bar-marker-pattern-shape

EDIT:

Due to a bug in {plotly}, the above code was not working correctly (shapes are not assigned to the correct traces).

The workaround is to sort the data.frame by color to make it work:

```
    plot_data[order(plot_data$color_var),] |>
      plot_ly() |> 
      add_bars(
        x = ~x_var,
        y = ~y_var,
        color = ~color_var,
        marker = list(
          pattern = list(
            shape = ~ifelse(pattern_var == 1, "/", "")
          )
        )
      )
```

[image: plot with correct shapes]

References to plotly issue can be found here:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1744

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1155

Comment: Why don't the patterns line up with `plot_data$pattern_var`? The dataframe specifies that x==1 and x==2 should have different patterns, but in the plot they're the same.

Comment: @filups21 Thanks for noticing this bug.
After testing it, it looks like there is a bug in {plotly} package. The data.frame seems to be modified (row orders) when using the "color" attribute.
Removing `color = ~color_var,` from code gives the right pattern but no color.
Reordering the data.frame by color also make it works..

The bug seems to be similar to these issues:
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1744 and https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1155